# get host name for jinja template in salt

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

not sure where to start but hre is what i have and what i'm trying to do.

what i have.

i have three Minions as part of three tier application named employee.

there is a three servers called web01 as web server, app01 as app server and a db01 as database server.

each server has a grains value on it,

here is each server and the grains values and keys of these values.

```
web01.
grains value =
appname:employee and
tier:web

app01.
grains value =
appname:employee and
tier:app

db01.
grains value =
appname:employee and 
tier:db
```

what i'm trying to do.

i'm trying to push configurations files on web01 and app01, these config files has a variables (hostname of another tier minion).. the config on the web01 should have the name app01.. and the config on app01 should have the name db01.. the name of these severs should be grabbed based on the grains value.

for example.

the host name of the app server, its the server that has grains value equal to "appname:employee and tier:app"

not sure how to do it.

too new to salt and i dont have much experiance with it nor jinja template.

any help will be really appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you right, you want the config file to be on web1 and app1 containing all hostnames.

If so, you can use a [pillar](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/pillar.html#more-complex-data) file where you state these attributes.

/srv/pillar/employee.sls:

```
employee:
  hostname_of_another_tier_minion: hostname.example.com
```

You can then reference this in your jinja template /srv/formulas/employee/templates/config.conf.jinja:

```
----------
hostname_of_another_tier_minion {{ pillar['employee']['hostname_of_another_tier_minion'] }}
```

Just to be complete you reference your template in /srv/employee/web.sls and /srv/employee/app.sls:

```
web-config-file:
  file.managed:
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - template: jinja
    - mode: '0644'
    - names:
      - /etc/<web-conf-dir>/web.conf:
        - source: salt://employee/templates/config.conf.jinja
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.

UPDATE:

If the hostnames are unknown as you said, you can first get them with [grains](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/grains/all/salt.grains.core.html#salt.grains.core.hostname) and then put them in the jinja template that gets rendered into a config on every server.

Comment: Thanks min, what you mentioned above is correct but, in my case the host name is unknown.. all what i know about the host is a couple of grains values.. its has "appname:employee" and "tier:db", 

so the jinja template should contains something like this. 

the db_server = (its is the server that comtains grains value "appname:employee" and "tier:db")

not sure how to get that. some people mentioned grains.filter_by but its not clear to me since this is a new world to me.

Comment: I see. So you want to get each hostname and then append them all in one config that is used by every server?

Comment: Thank you for the update and sorry for taking too long to comment here. i got busy on other project.

its exactly what you said in the update, but i dont know how to get the hostname with grains and pass it to pillar, i can simply hard coded the hostname on pillar if i know it, but since its unknown, i can simply do it like this

if grains['tier']['db'] 
then
employee:
  hostname_of_another_tier_minion: {% grains['fqdn'] %} 

but i dont know how to do it.